# See Code Reference through VSCODE like PYCHARM

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, reference

While using openCV-python in VSCODE. I wanted to see code reference, inside each .
I know that PYcharm supports to see inside each code of library, but do VSCODE also support to see code reference?

Comment: I would say don't restrict yourself to inbuilt code editor extensions to help with references, instead, use Python's inbuilt `help` function. You can use like `help(func_name)`

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/63905846

Answer (score 1):

##### right click --> *Go to References* or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what if it says this has no reference? Even if I'm importing from the library?